# Walking through the reduction of a cumulative probability function to a polynomial

Tags: probability, probability-theory, polynomials, probability-distributions, binomial-coefficients

## Setup

Define $P(p)$ as follows:

$$
P(p) = \sum_{N_1-\phi \cdot N_2 \geq \theta} {n_1 \choose N_1} {n_2 \choose N_2} p^{N_1 + N_2}q^{n_1 + n_2 - N_1 - N_2}.
$$

Here,

$$
q = 1 - p.
$$

The sum is over all $N_1$ and $N_2$ satisfying the following relation:

$$
N_1 - \phi N_2 \geq \theta.
$$

It should be noted that $0 \leq N_1 \leq n_1$, and the same holds for $N_2$ and $n_2$.

Now define $R(p)$ as follows:

$$
R(p) = p^{-1}P(p)
$$

when $p \neq 0$, and

$$
R(0) = \lim_{p \rightarrow 0} R(p).
$$

## Question(s)

Take $n_1=4, n_2=0, \theta=2,$ and $\phi=1$.  Can someone walk me through how this reduces $R(p)$ to

$$
R(p) = 6p - 8p^2+3p^3?
$$

I'm similarly confused about how $n_1=5, n_2=1, \theta=2,$ and $\phi=2$ reduces $R(p)$ to

$$
R(p) = 10p - 30p^2 + 35p^3 - 14p^4.
$$

Any nod in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ P(p) = \sum_{N_1 \geq N_2+2} \binom{4}{N_1}\binom{0}{N_2} p^{N_1+N_2}q^{4 - N_1 -N_2 }$$

$\binom{0}{x}$ is 1 if $x=0$ and 0 otherwise so the only $N_2$ That can affect the sum is $N_2 = 0$. similarly the other binomial coefficient is zero if $4=n_1<N_1$ so we don't have an infinite sum,

$$P(p) = \sum_{ k= 2}^{4} \binom{4}{k} p^k q^{4-k} $$

Typing on mobile is hard so I'll leave the rest to you.